# What is the difference between Anyways, Anyway and Any way?

Tags: informal-language

I have seen these words which looks pretty much the same in three different forms, why? what are the differences?

Which one is correct between **anyway** and **anyways**?
Are they spoken English or can I write those in my essays are they formal words?

> We're going to do it **anyway**!
>
> Great, the service was terrible, but **anyways** the meal was gorgeous.
>
> So, she's all "**Anyways**, let's go shopping at Target! "
>
> I do not know **any way** to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to the ELL, Roger :-). Can you please provide more details - what dictionary definitions have you checked, what do you find confusing in them, or examples of usage which you find confusing? You can find more about it in [this post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) :-).

Comment: The basic idea is *anyway* and *anyways* are about the same thing. (I'm an "anyway" person, BTW.) The important thing is that we don't write *anyway* (i.e. we must write *any way*) when we use it as a noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Any way*, written as two words, is the noun *way* with the quantifier *any* as its determiner.

> I don't know any way to fix it, but George may know a way to fix it.
>   There isn't any way I know of from here to there.

*Anyway* and *anyways* are adverbs. At one they were equivalent to *in any way* = *by any means, in any manner*, but in Modern English they're mostly<sup>†</sup> restricted to a contrastive sense approximately equivalent to *nonetheless* or *regardless*.

> [They told us not to do it, but] we're going to do it anyway.

It's often used to resume the thread of one's discourse after a digression, with a similar contrastive sense of "you can disregard all that".

Adverbial *anyway* no longer has any undertone of the original meaning, and it is spoken differently, with *-way* unstressed—which is probably why people started writing it differently.

The version with *-s* is a hangover from the Old and Middle English "adverbial genitive", in which the genitive form gave an adverbial sense. Some of these have survived in Standard English—*always*, *once*, *hence*, *towards*, and expressions like *he works night**s**—but the construction is not productive today, and most of these *-s* forms appear only in dialect. *Anyways* is one of those; it is not used in Standard speech or writing.

---

<sup>†</sup> You occasionally find uses in the old sense. For instance, *They scrape by anyway* may mean "They survive by any means they can", and "He does his work anyway* may mean "He does his work however it suits him, without any regard to its quality".